# Add route to use Wifi internet directly instead of VPN connection in MAC

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, vpn, ip, routing

I'm trying to add a route to **bypass** the **VPN** connection for **95.172.64.2** and just use the **Wifi** internet directly.

I'm using **Nord VPN** and it doesn't have a **split tunneling** option so I have to do it manually.

Here is my code, but it shows an error while my wifi connection IP is nothing else!

```
sudo route add 95.172.64.2 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.64
```

> route: invalid mask: 192.168.0.64